# Hyperlink in wrong location using POI and Jsoup

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, jsoup

I have a html table like this

```
| Data0 | Data1(with href) | Data2(with href) | Data3 |...| Data10 |
| Data0 | Data1(with href) | Data2(with href) | Data3 |...| Data10 |
```

---

**Update**: HTML codes of table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>...</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data0</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.abc1.org">Data1</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.abc2.org">Data2</a></td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td>Data4</td>
            ...
            <td>Data10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><!--2nd record--></tr>
        <tr><!--3rd record--></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

In the excel output, all text will be retrieved successfully.

---

**Purpose**: I want to have the hyperlink of Data1 embedded to the cell with the text "Data1", but my code will have the hyperlink embedded to "Data10".

Expected first row in excel:

```
| Data0 | Data1(with hyperlink to www.abc1.org) | Data2 | Data3 |...| Data10 |
```

Current output in excel:

```
| Data0 | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |...| Data10(with hyperlink to www.abc1.org) |
```

---

Part of my codes are here (the related codes):

```
    Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
    Elements tds = row.select("td");
    count = 0; //cell location at that row
    for (Element element : tds) {
            cell = header.createCell(count);            
            link.setAddress(row.select("td a[href]").first().attr("href")); 
            cell.setCellValue(element.text());
            cell.setHyperlink(link);    
            count++;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more clear about what html you parse. Can you post the relevant part of the html document? Also, try to strip out the excel stuff, so that people have no problem figuring out what JSoup problem you have. Or if it is an excel problem, try to reduce your code to the relevant part for this case. So it is unclear (to me) what you actually want, what you have, what you expect and what you got instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) You only have one**

```
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
```

In the loop you overwrite link each time with the *first* `td a` link inside the `row`.

To fix this, you probably need a new link instance for each link you want to use. (I am not familiar with apache-poi, so I might be wrong)

**1) The Css selector**

```
row.select("td a[href]").first().attr("href")
```

will select always the *first* href string in the first td in the row. I guess you want to select the href string corresponding to the `td`, if it exists.

**Proposed snippet**

```
Elements tds = row.select("td");
count = 0; //cell location at that row
for (Element element : tds) {
    cell = header.createCell(count);            

    cell.setCellValue(element.text());
    Element href = element.select("a[href]").first();
    if (href != null){
         Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
         link.setAddress(href.attr("href"));
         cell.setHyperlink(link); 
    }
    count++;
}
```

Note that my code is untested.

Comment: Test results: This will make both Data1 and Data2 with href but that's okay for me.

Comment: yes, i thought you wanted this. If you only want the first link you could check for that in the if clause. Like setting a boolean in the body of the if clause and check for this in the if statement. That way you enter the condition is only true for the first link.